# Do any media streaming servers for Linux support streaming (not just progressive download) of Windows Media formats?

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming, windows

Is it possible to build a Linux-only media streaming server which can do streaming of the formats supported by **Windows Media Services**? To the best of my knowledge, the popular streaming servers that run on Linux, like **Wowza** and **Darwin**, don't support this. Note that I mean proper streaming and **not [progressive download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download)**.

More generally, I wonder whether there are other features provided by Windows Media Services that can't be replicated on a Linux streaming server. In other words, what capabilities would I have to miss out on if my streaming server is Linux-only (so not even running a Windows VM image)?

Cheers,
Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the [Microsoft Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server) (MMS) protocols, I do not believe there are Open Source streaming servers available.

In Windows Media Services 2008, support was dropped for MMS in favor of [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).  Fortunately, this is supported outside of Windows.  There is a [list of Server Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol#Server_implementations) that include [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/) and [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/).

Typically when streaming from an Open Source platform to a Microsoft platform, I use [UPNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play).  I have had success and continue to use [ushare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/) for this purpose.  There is also a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers) with comparison of other UPNP software.

Comment: Thanks! This might be a separate question, but if MS dropped MMS, then what is the value proposition of Windows Media Services?

Answer (score 0):

I use a streaming server known as Red5 it is completely open source.
But in your case since you want to share files with Windows format that it still does not do.